# Find the size of the segment joining the foot of the perpendiculars of a scalene triangle

Tags: geometry

The sides of a scalene triangle measure 13, 14, and 15 units. Two outer bisectors of different angles are drawn and the third vertex is drawn perpendicular to these bisectors. Calculate the size of the segment joining the foot of these perpendiculars.(Answer:21)

[image]

My progress ..I thought of using sine theorem, cosine theorem and Pythagoras but it will be very complicated. There is probably a simpler solution

[image]

$D ~é ~excentro \therefore AD ~é~ bissetriz \triangle ABC\\
Teorema Bissetriz: \frac{BK}{AB}=\frac{KC}{AC}\rightarrow\frac{14-KC}{13}=\frac{KC}{15}\\
\therefore KC = 7,5 ~e~BK = 6,5\\
\triangle ABK\sim \triangle AML: Razão~Semelhança=\frac{13}{6,5} = 2\\
\therefore LM = \frac{6,5}{2}=3,25\\
De~forma~análoga: LN = 3,75\\
\triangle AHB: M(ponto~médio)\rightarrow HM = MB = 6,5\\
\triangle ACI:N(ponto ~médio) \rightarrow NI = NC = 7,5\\
\therefore \boxed{\color{red}x = 6,5+3,25+3,75+7,5 = 21 }$

Comment: What are you looking for? Do you want us to complete your solution, or come up with something else? Were you able to finish this off?

Comment: @Ritam_Dasgupta ..I need a solution...the way I imagined I couldn't finish...there must be a simpler way with auxiliary lines

Comment: I think I've figured it out...Using the bisector theorem and triangle similarity we find that MN is base-average(M intersection of x with AB and N with AC. ML =3.25 and LN = 3.75. MH = MB = 6 .5 and NC = NI = 7.5
Therefore x = 6.5+7.5+3.25+3.75 = 21

Comment: This is good. You should edit the question and add this solution as your progress or answer your own question with adding appropriate details. I just posted my solution. I find $MN$ directly and do not have to find $ML$ and $LN$ separately.

Comment: @MathLover there is a flaw in my solution...you need to demonstrate that the triangles are similar...couldn't demonstrate

Comment: @MathLover  ok,,added my progress

Comment: @MathLover  can explain better? $\angle ADB = 90^0 - \cfrac{\angle B}{2} - \cfrac{\angle A}{2} = \cfrac{\angle C}{2}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

As $D$ is intersection of external bisectors of $\angle B$ and $\angle C$, $AD$ must be internal bisector of $\angle A$.

So, $\angle ADB = 90^0 - \cfrac{\angle B}{2} - \cfrac{\angle A}{2} = \cfrac{\angle C}{2}$

Similarly, $\angle ADC = \cfrac{\angle B}{2}$

Now notice that quadrilateral $AIDH$ is cyclic.

So, $\angle AHI = \angle ADC = \cfrac{\angle B}{2}$

Also, $\angle BAH = \cfrac{\angle B}{2} = \angle AHI$. So $M$ is the midpoint of $AB$.

And similarly, it follows that $N$ is the midpoint of $AC$.

That leads to $HI = HM + MN + NI$

$= AM + \cfrac{BC}{2} + AN = 6.5 + 7 + 7.5 = 21$

Comment: @petaarantes you are welcome. Let me know if anything is not clear.

Comment: @petaarantes $\angle ADB + \angle BAD = 90^0 - \frac{\angle B}{2}$, right?

Comment: @petaarantes or if that is not clear, see it this way - $\angle ADB = 180^0 - \angle BAD - \angle ABD$. Now $\angle ABD = \angle B + \frac{180^0 - \angle B}{2} = 90^0 + \frac{\angle B}{2}$ and $\angle BAD = \frac{\angle A}{2}$. So you can find $\angle ADB$. Lastly use $ \frac{\angle A + \angle B + \angle C}{2} = 90^0 \implies 90^0 - \frac{\angle A + \angle B}{2} = \frac{\angle C}{2}$.

Comment: ,,Perfect,,great!!

Answer (score 1):

The way you had started does lead to a solution, although it is a little calculative. Note that:
$$AH=13 \cos \left(\frac {\beta}{2}\right)$$
$$AI=15 \cos \left(\frac {\gamma}{2} \right)$$
Also, $\angle AHI=\alpha +\frac {\beta+\gamma}{2}=90°+\frac {\alpha}{2}$.
Now, let $HI=x$. From the cosine law on $\Delta HAI$, we have:
$$\cos (\angle AHI)=\cos\left(90°+\frac {\alpha}{2}\right)=-\sin \frac {\alpha}{2}=\frac {AH^2+HI^2-x^2}{2 AH \cdot AI}$$
Thus, $$x=\sqrt {AH^2+HI^2-2 AH \cdot AI \sin \frac {\alpha}{2}} {\tag 1}$$
Now, use the formulae:
$$\cos \frac {\alpha}{2}=\sqrt {\frac {s(s-a)}{bc}}$$
$$\cos \frac {\beta}{2}=\sqrt {\frac {s(s-b)}{ac}}$$
$$\cos \frac {\gamma}{2}=\sqrt {\frac {s(s-c)}{ab}}$$
Here $a=14$, $b=15$ and $c=13$, while $s=\frac {a+b+c}{2}=21$.
Hence, all the half-angle trig values are known, and can be substituted back in $(1)$ to obtain the answer.